# Поменять местами min и max в файле

Tags: c++

Добрый день. У меня есть программа

```
//запись в файл
time_t temp = time(NULL);
srand(temp);
ofstream out("d:\\txtFile.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    tmp = rand() % 10001 - 5000;
    out.write((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    cout << tmp << " ";
}
out.close();
cout << endl << endl;


// чтение и поиск min, max
int min = 6000, max = -6000;
ifstream in("d:\\txtFile.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    in.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    if (tmp < min) min = tmp;
    if (tmp > max) max = tmp;

}
cout << "min=" << min << endl;
cout << "max=" << max << endl<<endl;
in.close();


//меняем местами минимальный и максимальный элементы
...
system("pause");
```

Но я не понимаю как поменять местами min и max уже непосредственно в файле. Я пытался записывать числа из файла в вектор и в массив, но в итоге в векторе и в массиве получается совершенно другое число. Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Вот код вектора

```
std::vector<char>numbers;
int number;
while (in1 >> number)
{
    numbers.push_back(number);
}
cout << number;
```

В нем я, конечно, пока не меняю местами минимальный и максимальный элементы, но в самом выводе получается -858993460, что является не верным

---

Да, это весь код вектора, мне главное записать в него числа из файла, а дальше в принципе понятно что делать. Если нужно туда что-то дописать в него, тогда скажите что именно, я просто не знаю что еще нужно для записи в вектор)

Comment: Идея правильная. Покажите код с вектором, скорее всего проблема там. P.S. Но вообще смешивать `time_t` и `int` - уже криво.

Comment: Внесите дополнительную информацию в вопрос путем его редактирования (ссылка `править` под телом вопроса), а не добавления в виде ответа.